# Handling conflicting addon keyboard shortcuts in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

I currently have both the [To Google Translate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/to-google-translate/) and [Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) add-ons installed in Firefox. The Ctrl + . keyboard shortcut for Multi-Account Containers doesn't work for me, but the Ctrl + Shift + 1-9 shortcuts do.

Unfortunately, To Google Translate also takes the same keyboard shortcut for Ctrl + Shift + 1-3, and doesn't offer the option to disable them. Currently, using those shortcuts opens Google Translate, when I'd prefer them to open Multi-Account Containers.

Is there some way to direct Firefox to favour the Multi-Account Container plugin for keyboard shortcuts, or disable shortcut commands for To Google Translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Firefox favours keyboard shortcut priority based on add-on seniority — whichever add-on was installed or activated the *most* recently gets the *lowest* priority. Disabling To Google Translate and then reactivating it seems to have made Firefox think it's "newer" and thus lower priority, and the Ctrl + Shift + 1-9 shortcuts now work for Multi-Account Containers instead.

Comment: It's not Firefox but Windows.